# Closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

If $S=\{[y\cdot z,y,z]^T \mid y, z \in \mathbb{R}\},$

is $S$ closed under addition and scalar multiplication? This one confuses me as there are not restrictions to what part of $\mathbb{R}^3$ our vectors in the set lives. This leads me to believe that it is closed because any two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ when added or multiplied by a scalar would still be in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

P.S. I didn't come up with this problem.

Comment: No it is not y^z

Answer (score 4):

S is restricted to elements where the first element is the product of the other two, so if you multiply the vector [1,1,1] by 2, the result [2,2,2] does not meet the criteria anymore.